# Text with addslashes breaking when fetch in textfield

Tags: php

Record in Database looks like this:

```
D\'Huison-Longueville
```

When I echo this record in textfield it appears like this :

```
D
```

**Here is my code:**

```
<input type="text" name="city" value="<?php echo stripslashes($query['city']); ?>" />
```

Original text was:

`D'Huison-Longueville`

so I had to use

```
addslashes($_POST['city']);
```

Without stripslashes it appears like this :

```
D\
```

Comment: why is the \ in the db in the first place? it shouldent be, so the problem is how you insert, not how you select

Comment: Question is unclear, improve your question by adding some more details.

Comment: Also, include the rendered code please (the html literal).

Comment: http://codepad.org/BPicP6Rw

Comment: `echo $query['city']` without stripslashes, then whats the output..?

Comment: Original text was: D'Huison-Longueville so I had to use addslashes($_POST['city']);

Comment: Post Updated please review it

Comment: then you need to check the `value=""` or `value=''` inside the input element

Comment: Issue resolved. I used value='' instead of value=""

Comment: dont ever use add slashes when adding to the bd, sanitise properly

Comment: but we can do in that case if we are getting data in slashes form ?